# scala future error for " Don't call `Awaitable` methods directly, use the `Await` object."

Tags: scala, asynchronous

My trait method is:

```
userService{
  def link(current: U, to:User): Future[U]
  def findUserByEmail(email:String):Future[Option[User]]
}
```

when I execute I use:

```
for(link(currentUser, userService.findUserByEmail(email).result(Duration(1000, MILLISECONDS)).get)){
...
}
```

and the error is:

```
[error] G:\testprojects\mifun\modules\app\controllers\
ProviderController.scala:130: Don't call `Awaitable` methods directly, use the `
Await` object.
```

I do not know why here must use await object instead of awaitable methods, and how to change it correctly.

Comment: By the way, reading [canonical Futures and Promises tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) might be beneficial for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to block you need to use `Await.result(userService.findUserByEmail(email), 1000 millis)`, note that blocking is in general a bad idea as it blocks your main thread waiting for the specified result to return, take a look at [`onComplete`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) for example.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
val futureLink = findUserByEmail(user) flatMap {
  maybeUser => maybeUser map (user => link(currentUser, user))
}

futureLink onComplete {
    case Success(user:User) => ...
    case Success(None) => ...
    case Failure(ex) => ...
}
```

or, if you really need to block, you can do `Await.result` on `futureLink`.